# How I can hide some x axis labels in seaborn time-series plot?

Tags: time-series, seaborn, line-plot, x-axis, xticks

I'm using sns.scatterplot and sns.lineplot to show my time-series data (1-min interval CO2 concentration). I have almost 1 month datasets which makes the x-axis very packed (since I have 40'000 datapoint).

the data starts 2022-05-02 00:00 and ends 2022-06-02 23:58:00. Can anyone help me to list up only 00:00 (12am) and 12:00 (12pm) - so two datapoints for each day?

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,4))
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x = "Time", y = "A147_CO2", hue = "Week", linewidth=2.5)
a= df['Time']
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len(a) + 1, 5))
plt.xticks(rotation = 45)

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
```

[X-axis is too packed!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe35g.png)

Comment: You need to represent your time data with a datetime dtype.

Comment: @mwaskom Could you give an example?

Comment: Use `df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time)` to converte the `'Time'` column to a datetime dtype